# How to write a unit test which tests Mono error?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am new to Spring Webflux and I want to know what is the best way to write a unit test to check if an error is being thrown:

```
public Mono<String> update(UpdateModel updateModel) {
        return webClient.post()
                .uri(updatePath)
                .bodyValue(updateModel)
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(httpStatus -> !HttpStatus.OK.equals(httpStatus),
                        clientResponse -> Mono.error(new ServerSideException("Failed to update")))
                .bodyToMono(String.class);
    }
```

What is the best way to write a unit test ?

This is what I am using:

```
@Test
public void shouldThrowServerErrorIfUpdateServiceCallFails() {
    when(responseSpecMock.onStatus(any(), any())).thenReturn(responseSpecMock);
    when(responseSpecMock.bodyToMono(String.class)).thenReturn(Mono.error(new ServerSideException("Failed to update")));

    var response = client.update(updateModel);

    StepVerifier.create(response)
            .expectError(ServerSideException.class)
            .verify();
}
```

The error is actually thrown from the lambda, not being thrown from `bodyToMono` call.

This is obviously not correct, but I don't know any better way to check it via unit test.

Comment: ”best way” is subjective voted to close this will lead to opinion based answers.

Comment: A unit test tests a “unit”. Internal implementation should not be relevant. Does the method under test produce the right output for the right input?

Comment: @Toerktumlare It's a legitimate problem; the OP is probably interested in learning about different ways to solve it -- "best" is not the keyword here, "I don't know any better way" is

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, the best way to test how WebFlux behaves in both normal and error scenarios is to set up a test web server with [Wiremock](http://wiremock.org/) or [Mountebank](http://www.mbtest.org/) and avoid mocking completely.  This way you are assured that your tests are exercising the WebFlux code in the same way as in real life.

Mocking and stubbing is very useful when used appropriately, but they are usually a waste of time when testing 3rd party libraries such as WebFlux.  Shameless plug: I wrote an [article to explain this point in more detail](https://medium.com/@xpmatteo/how-i-learned-to-love-mocks-1-fb341b71328).

Comment: I would argue that using integration testing tools for unit tests is a dangerous path. It’s certainly perfectly valid to have a few “end to end” type tests to ensure that all the plumping works; but testing specifics should be kept in as small a scope as possible as the permutations get large quickly and the tests need to remain fast.

Comment: @BoristheSpider reducing combinational complexity is exactly one of the reasons why it's useful to write *focused* integration tests; they are called "focused" because they focus on a single integration point. Another case where they are very useful, besides http proxies, is testing DB-based repositories.

Comment: @xpmatteo So when we use WebFlux we can't right unit tests right ? We can only go for integration tests with `WireMock`. Am I correct ?

Comment: Another helpful tool to mock webserver is https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver - I use it very often to test implementations that use Spring's WebClient and WebFlux.

Comment: @ng.newbie What I usually do is to encapsulate the WebFlux logic in an adapter; the adapter provides a convenient interface that talks my domain. I test the adapter with Wiremock, and I test the code that uses the adapter by mocking or stubbing the adapter.